# how to avoid pyparsing from parsing 5+5+ and 5+5++++ and 5+5everything

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm quite new with pyparsing and I have these rules:

```
num = Word(nums)
op = Word("+-*/", max=1)
base = num + op + num
```

then I have this:

```
try:
   base.parseString(base, "5+5")
except ParseException as exc:
   print (exc)
```

`5+5` works perfectly, but also `5+5+`, `5+5++`, `5+5++++whatever`.

All of them output the same: `(['5', '+', '5'], {})`

I'm using Python 3.6.7 and I wonder how can I fix this? What am I missing here?